# How to calculate the number of waters of hydration?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, stoichiometry

I have three questions about waters of hydration, the first two of which I'm really stuck on:

1. A sample of cobalt(II) nitrate hydrate was heated to remove all the water of hydration. The hydrate was found to be $65.96\%$ oxygen. Calculate the number of water molecules associated with each formula unit of cobalt(II) nitrate.
2. Epsom salts is $\ce{MgSO4.xH2O}$. The hydrate was found to contain $71.4\%$ oxygen. Calculate the  value of $x$.
3. Zinc nitrate $\ce{Zn(NO3)2.xH2O}$ contains $21.98\%$ zinc by mass. What is the value of $x$?

I have absolutely no idea for the first two questions.

For the third:

1. Assume $\pu{100 g}$ of material
2. $\pu{21.98 g}$ of Zn = $\pu{0.3284 mol}$ of $\ce{Zn}$

I couldn't get any further than this.

Comment: Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the questions involve the same reasoning, so let's look at question #2.

What is the % oxygen in $\ce{MgSO4}$ when there is no water of hydration (x=0)?  It would be given by $$\mathrm{\%~ oxygen~ =~ \frac{(4 \cdot atomic~ wgt~ O)}{(atomic~wgt~ Mg + atomic~ wgt~S + (4 \cdot atomic~ wgt~ O))}}\\\mathrm{=~\frac{(4 \cdot 16)}{(24_{.}31+32+(4 \cdot 16))}}\\=53.2\%$$  How would the equation change if we added one $\ce{H2O}$ of hydration to the molecular formula? How about if we added 2 or 3?

Comment: I realize the percent of oxygen would go up by about 3.5% each time I add in an extra H2O. It is possible to do trial and error until I get to 71.4% but there has to be a more efficient way of doing this right?

Comment: sure, set up an equation like above but insert "x" times the atomic weights for the contributions from the H and O in the water